# Проверка на родительский элемент

Tags: javascript, функции, dom

Привет, помогите пожалуйста с задачей. Функция принимает два элемента, и проверяет на то, является ли первый элемент родителем для второго.

```
isParent(document.body.children[0], document.querySelector('mark'));
// true
isParent(document.querySelector('ul'), document.querySelector('mark'));
// false
```

У меня пока такой код:

```js
function isParent(parent, child) {
    return child.parentNode===parent;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <article>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, odio omnesque ius cu, quo ex atqui antiopam. At detracto menandri eos. Duo in causae viderer, graeci <a href="#">reprehendunt</a> has in. Decore <mark>nemore</mark> philosophia te pro, nobis legere causae ex mei, odio putant mentitum ea ius. Vix nostro deserunt explicari eu.</p>
    </article>
</div>
<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
</ul><span></span>
<a href="#">Some link</a>
 
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

А надо, чтобы было сделано через функцию:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.clear();
    // код
    function isParent(parent, child) {

    }
});
```

Comment: а чем стандартная функция compareDocumentPosition не подходит?

Answer (score 0):

```
function isParent(parent, child) {
  if (parent && child) {
    var current = child.parentNode;
    while (current) {
      if (current == parent)
        return true;
      current = current.parentNode;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```